# Content Search Webpart not getting Picture URL

Tags: 2013, display-template, content-search-web-part

I've built a DisplayTemplate (ItemTemplate) for a ContentSearchWebPart. It works quite well for different fields, but I don't get my PublishingImage from the pages I'm querying.
The ManagedPropertyMapping is as follows:

```
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'Picture URL'{Picture URL}:'PublishingImage','Link URL'{Link URL}:'Path','Line 1'{Line 1}:'Title','Line 2'{Line 2}:'Description','Line 3'{Line 3}:''</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>
```

I also tried the following Version, but It also doesn't works:

```
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'Picture URL'{Picture URL}:'PublishingImage;PictureURL;PictureThumbnailURL', ......
```

In the following code "pictureURL" is empty while my other itemvalues are correct.

```
var pictureURL = $getItemValue(ctx, "Picture URL");
```

Has anybody an idea what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: before crawling, did you see grey boxes with a questionmark instead of pictures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tries, I recognized that the code (display temaplte) works. I had to run the search crawler (full crawl) one more time.